# Gauge invariance of 2-to-2 scattering at order $e^4$ in scalar QED

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, gauge-invariance

I am trying to show explicitly that the amplitude for the scattering of two scalar particles at order $e^4$ is gauge-independent. The Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L}= (D^\mu \chi_1)^\dagger (D_\mu \chi_1) - m_1^2 \chi_1^\dagger \chi_1
+ (D^\mu \chi_2)^\dagger (D_\mu \chi_2) - m_2^2 \chi_2^\dagger \chi_2
- \frac14 F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu},$$

where $D_\mu$ and $F_{\mu \nu}$ are the usual covariant derivative and electromagnetic field strength tensor. Basically the scalar QED Lagrangian but with 2 different scalars, so there are two types of vertices for each scalar: scalar-scalar-photon vertex and scalar-scalar-photon-photon vertex with the Feynman rules for them from the usual scalar QED.

The incoming states are $p_1$ and $p_2$ and the outgoing states are $p'_1$ and $p'_2$ with $(p_1)^2=(p'_1)^2=m_1^2$ and $(p_2)^2=(p'_2)^2=m_2^2$. I am using the form of the photon propagator given in Peskin and Schroeder eq. (9.58), $$\frac{-i}{k^2+i \epsilon}\left(g^{\mu\nu}-(1-\xi)\frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{k^2}\right).$$

So I am trying to show that the sum of all Feynman diagrams (see picture) of order $e^4$ for this process is independent of $\xi$. I was able to show that the sum of the first three diagrams is independent of $\xi$ by following the idea from pages 7 and 8 of this [II-2: Scalar QED pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=scalar+qed+II&oq=scalar+qed+II&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61l2.9233j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and replacing the propagator and external lines of the bottom part of the diagrams by a common "blob". I also showed that the last diagram (for either $\chi_1$ or $\chi_2$) is independent of $\xi$ by itself, but when calculating the sum of the $4^{th}$ and $5^{th}$ diagrams I don't get the $\xi$ terms vanishing, so I think the sum of these two diagrams is gauge dependent.

[image]

It makes sense when comparing this with the sum of the first three diagrams because one could do a similar thing for the $4^{th}$ and $5^{th}$ diagrams and replace the bottom external legs with a common "blob" and follow the same approach as for the sum of the first three diagrams. However, in this case, there is no "cross-box" diagram and that was needed to get the gauge independence of the sum of the first three diagrams.

So then I get that the sum of all these diagrams at this order is gauge dependent which obviously can't be correct. This leads me to believe there are actually more diagrams at this order that I haven't considered and presumably when adding them to those that I have considered will cancel any $\xi$ dependence, but I can't think of any other valid diagrams at this order. I would appreciate any help with this!